# How to pop out a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have embedded a google form in a chrome extension. However, because of :https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq#faq-persist-popups

Whenever someone clicks outside the extension pop up, it closes the extension. 
Is there a way I can pop out my dialog box so that users are free to click on the active tab and make recordings in the form?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do that is to insert using content script a custom iframe, which will contain the same scripts/html as the regular popup. An iframe will let you isolate the html & stylesheets from interaction with existing site's web page.
The iframe html file should be listed as [web accessible resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) in `manifest.json`.

The content script will handle the iframe display when clicking on the browser icon.

For example, [Evernote web clipper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evernote-web-clipper/pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc?hl=en) is using this approach.

Code samples that may help you:

1) Define the browser action in your `manifest.json` file (do no indicate the popup property) and make the `popup.html` as web accessible:

```
{
    "name": "My extension",
    ...
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {                      // optional
        "19": "images/icon19.png",           // optional
        "38": "images/icon38.png"            // optional
      }
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": ["popup.html"]
  }
```

2) Create the `popup.html` file which holds the html & css of your popup;

3) Create the `background.js` script which will listen for browser action clicks and sends the message to content script:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab){
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, 'browser_action_click', function(callback_data) {
      });
})
```

4) In your `content_script.js` listen for browser action clicks messages from background, and show/hide the iframe:

```
var show = false;

var controller = {
  insertIframe: function (){
    var iFrame  = document.createElement("iframe");
    iFrame.setAttribute('style', '');
    iFrame.setAttribute('id', 'popup_iframe');
    iFrame.src  = chrome.extension.getURL ("popup.html");
    if (document.body) {
      //sometimes document body is not loaded yet. Just skip
      document.body.insertBefore(iFrame, document.body.firstChild);
    }
  },
  getIframe: function() {
    return document.getElementById('popup_iframe');
  },
  hideIframe: function() {
    var iframe = this.getIframe();
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
  },
  showIframe: function() {
    var iframe = this.getIframe();
    iframe.style.display = 'block';
  },
  listenForMessages: function() {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
      switch(request) {
        case 'browser_action_click':
          show = !show;
          show ? this.showIframe() : this.hideIframe();
      }
      return true;
    }.bind(this));
  }
};

controller.insertIframe();
controller.listenForMessages();
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. Any sample code you can help me with?

Comment: Hey Dmitri,
I tried using this but somehow it doesnt work. I click on the browser button but its not creating the iFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Consider making it without popup, but with a `content script`.

The idea is that by clicking your extension's icon script will insert a form to the DOM of an active tab.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a separate window with `chrome.windows.create` with `type: "popup"`.

Note, however, that there is no way to make it stay on top.